# Parsing a database column into individual columns

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to parse some data stored in a database column into individual columns.  The data can vary in length.  I want to name the database column the name of the value being parsed. e.g number=12345 the column should be called number, the value in the column should be 12345

An example of the data stored in a column:

```
id  text
___________________________________________________________________________
1   Re: Fwd: number=12345:bottle=glass:water=sparkling:food=chocolate
2   number=223344:bottle=plastic:water=still:food=sweets:biscuit=digestive
```

What I would like is the following:

```
id Re  Fwd number  bottle  water       food        biscuit
__________________________________________________________________
1   Re  Fwd 12345   glass   sparkling   chocolate null
2   null null 223344  plastic still       sweets      digestive
```

I've tried `(select string_to_array (text, ':') from my_table)` but which splits the data but not how I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table to insert to:

```
create table s201 (id int,Re text, Fwd text,number int, bottle text, water text,      food  text,      biscuit text);
```

query:

```
with pre as (
with a(k,v) as (
    values (1,'Re: Fwd: number=12345:bottle=glass:water=sparkling:food=chocolate'),(2,'number=223344:bottle=plastic:water=still:food=sweets:biscuit=digestive')
  )
  , col(s,n) as (select * from unnest(array['Re','Fwd','number','bottle','water','food','biscuit'])  with ordinality c (s,n))
select s,n,k, case when o not like '%=%' then trim(o) else  split_part(trim(o),'=',2) end c
from col
join a on true
left outer join unnest(string_to_array(a.v,':')) with ordinality t (o,i) on split_part(trim(o),'=',1) = s
)
, agg as (
select k, array_agg(c order by n) a
from pre
group by k
)
insert into s201
select k,a[1],a[2],a[3]::int,a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7]
from agg;
```

> INSERT 0 2

checking:

```
select * from s201;
 id | re | fwd | number | bottle  |   water   |   food    |  biscuit
----+----+-----+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------
  1 | Re | Fwd |  12345 | glass   | sparkling | chocolate |
  2 |    |     | 223344 | plastic | still     | sweets    | digestive
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you.  It looks horrible but does what I want it to do!

Comment: Please don't forget to accept it if nobody offers a better solution

Comment: I'm struggling with replacing the values with the actual database data

I'm trying to do this but can't get it to work

'with a(k,v) as (
    values (select id, parsing_column from mytable)
  )'

Also, as I don't know what the parsing_column will contain, I can't create a temporary table as I don't know how many columns there will be

I can get the max number of values doing this 'select max(array_length(string_to_array (parsing_column, ':'), 1)) from mytable;' but unsure how to create the table from this

Comment: `with a(k,v) as ( values (select id, parsing_column from mytable) )` change to `with a(k,v) as ( select id, parsing_column from mytable)`, regarding the rest - if you don't find anything, ask a new question - so one answer would be for one question