# Unnest a column

Tags: postgresql

I have some sql which has some hard coded values which I am trying to replace with values from a database column

```
with pre as (
with a(k, v) as (select id, my_column from mytable), 
col(s, n) as (select * from unnest(array['Title', 'First', 'Middle', 'Last']) with ordinality c (s, n))
```

I'm trying to replace the unnest sql with something like this:

```
select unnest(string_to_array(my_column, ':')) as elements from mytable
```

mycolumn contents vary in length but an example could be title=aaa:first=bbb:middle=ccc:last=ddd

Thanks

Comment: I answered with example of how to select from table instead of "hardcoded values". Please elaborate the question - I would not understand what you ask if we did not chat before

Answer (score 0):

I base my answer [on your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540554/parsing-a-database-column-into-individual-columns). Here is an example of how you can join `unnest(string_to_array(my_column, ':'))` with named columns on ordinality:

```
t=# with a as (select id,k,v from my_table, unnest(string_to_array(my_column, ':')) with ordinality as t(k,v))
, col(s, n) as (select * from unnest(array['Title', 'First', 'Middle', 'Last']) with ordinality c (s, n))
select * from a join col on n=v;
 id |     k      | v |   s    | n
----+------------+---+--------+---
  1 | title=aaa  | 1 | Title  | 1
  1 | first=bbb  | 2 | First  | 2
  1 | middle=ccc | 3 | Middle | 3
  1 | last=ddd   | 4 | Last   | 4
(4 rows)
```

Of course you will have to join differently (based on your previous post). But if the unclear part was how you select from table instead of select from values, the example above should help.

**update**

put values to table:

```
t=# create table keys(t text);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 91.908 ms
t=# insert into keys select unnest(array['Title', 'First', 'Middle', 'Last']);
INSERT 0 4
Time: 11.552 ms
t=# select * from keys ;
   t
--------
 Title
 First
 Middle
 Last
(4 rows)
```

and now join against keys table:

```
t=# with a as (select id,k,v from my_table, unnest(string_to_array(my_column, ':')) with ordinality as t(k,v))
select * from a join keys on split_part(k,'=',1) = lower(t);
 id |     k      | v |   t
----+------------+---+--------
  1 | first=bbb  | 2 | First
  1 | last=ddd   | 4 | Last
  1 | middle=ccc | 3 | Middle
  1 | title=aaa  | 1 | Title
(4 rows)
```

Comment: It's this part I have a problem with select * from unnest(array['Title', 'First', 'Middle', 'Last'] as I don't know what these will be, so i want to get the value from the column and not hard code them

Comment: I'm still confused! If I say select my_column from my_table, the contents could be anything, e.g.

my_column
----------
first=aaa:last=bbb:middle=ccc:bottle=ddd:table=ddd

In the create table, I need the values from the my_column, I can't hard code them as I don't know what they will be. I'm trying to unnest my_column by : and then split them by = and use the first part before the = as the table column name. So I'm trying to do something like this, but I don't know the correct sql

select unnest(string_to_array(my_column, ':')) as my_new_column from my_table, then split_part by '='

Comment: I can do this select s.my_new_items, id from my_table t, unnest(string_to_array(t.my_column, ':')) s(my_new_items), which parses them into rows, I now trying to get the first part before the '=' to create then table column names